# Как сделать загрузочную флешку с помощью bin файла

Tags: ассемблер, bios, fasm, загрузчик

Я написал ОС на ассемблере, и мне нужно сделать загрузочную флешку, чтобы загрузить свою ОС на свой старый компьютер и протестировать ее в реальных условиях

На эмуляторе все работает
ОС моя находится в bin-файле

Comment: Нужно - делайте. Загрузочная флешка ничем не отличается от загрузочного жёсткого диска или дискетки (а основное отличие от загрузочного сидюка - в размере сектора). Для бутсектора придётся написать модуль поиска и загрузки BIN с операционкой - либо весь образ, если он бут-загружаемый, положить в бутблок раздела.

Comment: @Akina, скорее всего я неправильно сформировал вопрос. Мне нужно создать iso-файл с моим bin-файлом, который должен будет загружаться.